# Binding to Parent of Unknown Type

Tags: wpf, data-binding, controltemplate

I have a style and template for a tooltip and would like to bind some of the content in the tooltip to the parent's error collection. I can get this to work by explicitly setting the AncestorType like in the code below, but I would like this to apply globally. I've tried using UIElement and FrameworkElement with no luck, but I think that's because it's not getting all of the way up the tree to find the correct element.

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger
              Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TextBox}}, Path=(Validation.HasError)}"
              Value="True">
              <Setter
                Property="Visibility"
                TargetName="ErrorBorder"
                Value="Visible" />
              <Setter
                Property="Text"
                TargetName="ErrorText"
                Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TextBox}}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
            </DataTrigger>
          </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Comment: So you want this assignment to bubble up the logical tree until it finds an element that can take the binding, and then assign it? I don't you will be able to do this in Xaml.

Answer (score 1):

Simple just try,

```
 AncestorType=Control
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use AncestorLevel in the RelativeSource.

Comment: That's assuming the parent element that has the validation is always at the same level, which I can't guarantee. I've tried this approach anyway using Control, FrameworkElement, and UIElement and haven't had luck.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by binding to the PlacementTarget of the tooltip using the following binding:

```
{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=PlacementTarget.(Validation.HasError)}"
```

This seems to be working well as long as the PlacementTarget for the tooltip is the control that has the error validation, which in my case it is.